# A verb to connect apps with the devices they are run on

Tags: word-request, verbs

I want to say people are thinking of applications **after** a device is built. For example, consider a new platform, such as a smart watch. After smart watches have been developed and become mainstream, people are thinking of new applications for it. So, we might say:

> Many different applications are _______ for this new device.

What is a good verb to use here?

I was thinking of **"defined"**, but it seems there should be a better choice. (Of course the preposition "for" can be changed according to the verb).

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Very often we see "available" filling that slot.

Comment: @TRomano, see the edit.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want to say. People are thinking of these devices is very vague.

Comment: How about 'Many different applications arise for this new device.'?

Comment: I think this could be a very good ELL question - you just need to give everyone a better idea of what you are trying to say with the word you are looking for.

Comment: @J.R. The problem is I don't know how to make it clearer. What I had in mind as an example was something like *smartwatches*: When it is developed and become mainstream, people are thinking/... of new applications for it. Hence, the sentence in question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear what the question is asking.

Answer (score 3):

More context is needed. What do you want to say? I can think of several sentences. Say --

> Many different applications are ***compatible*** with this new device *(preposition 'for' changed, as you suggested)*.
>
> Many different applications are ***meant*** for this new device
>
> Many different applications are ***built/made*** for this new device

And, so on...

---

After OP's edit

Well, in that case....I'd rephrase it to say that people started thinking *after* this device...

> Many different apps ***have been thought of*** for this new device
>
> Many different apps ***have been planned*** because of/after this new device

Or, in a professional way... I may prefer writing...

> This device has opened great opportunities for different types of applications

---

After OP's comment clarifying the question further *(from developers' perspective)* -

> *"The popularity and uniqueness of smartwatches have encouraged apps developers to come up with innovative applications"*

Should there be further clarification, I edit this further.

Answer (score 2):

How about "conceivable"? In this case, it would say that one can imagine many different ways to use the new device.

You might also consider "devise", as in "Many applications *may be devised* for this new device." It points out that there are multiple ways that one can apply the device, and you get bonus points for knowing to differentiate between device and devise. :D

Answer (score 1):

Proposed, has been proposed,if you want a verb

Possible is fine too but an adjective

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking from the developer's vantage point, you might say:

> Many different applications are being **designed** for this new device.

This would mean, for example, that new applications are being built for that specific device. The verb "designed" would imply that that new apps account for factors such as screen size, available bandwidth, and likely peripheral devices.

That said, there are plenty of other verbs that could complete the sentence, and the verb you choose depends a lot on who is talking. For example, a company that develops new apps might say:

> Many different applications are being **written** for this new device.

whereas an advertising executive might say:

> Many different applications are being **marketed** for this new device.

and a customer might notice:

> Many different applications are being **sold** for this new device.

Comment: You can also add "engineered", "developed".